# Prove that if n + 1 integers are chosen from the set of all positive ints up to 2n, there will always be two among the selected ints whose gcd is $1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We select $n + 1$ different integers from the set of all positive integers up to $2n$ for some positive integer $n$. Prove that there will always be two among the selected integers whose greatest common divisor is $1$.

Comment: An important rule of MSE is that you are also expected to present your work on your problem.

Comment: The two answers currently posted boil down to this: if you pick $n+1$ numbers from $1$ to $2n$, then there must be two of them that differ by $1$.

Comment: @TonyK Close this as as duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3001017/357390), after my answer gets upvoted. I am out of close votes for the day.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: it doesn't look like a duplicate to me!

Comment: @TonyK It is an abstract duplicate, and I have provided a generalised answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S$ be the set of all positive integers up to $2n$ for some positive integer $n$, and $X$ be the set of all subsets $A$ of $S$ such that the cardinality of $A$ is $n + 1$.

Suppose, to produce a set $A$ in $X$, we've selected $n - k$ different even numbers from $S$ for some integer $k$ such that $0 ≤ k ≤ n - 1$ $($since we can select at most $n$ evens and we need to select at least $1$ even from $S)$. And we want to select other $k + 1$ number(s) as odd number(s).

Now, for the $k + 1$ odd number(s), we must pick at least $1$ odd number
$2b - 1$ from $S$ such that its successor even number $2b$ is in $A$. That's because, for any $2m$ from our unselected $k$ even number(s) in $S$, we've $2m - 1$ to choose from $S$. But hey! even if we choose $k$ odd number(s) which doesn't have their successor even number in $A$, since we need to select $k + 1$ odd number(s), for the $(k + 1)$-th odd number, we must choose an odd number $2b - 1$ from $S$ which does have a successor even number $2b$ in $A$ $($since we don't have any other unselected even number $2m$ left in $S$ to choose another $2m - 1)$. Then we've $\gcd(2b - 1, 2b) = 1$, which proves our proposition. $\blacksquare$

Edit: I've found a nice idea in explaining the Stinking Bishop's answer to the OP. I believe it would be more easy-going than my previous proof.

We need at least $1$ pair of coprime integers in our $n+1$ numbers to show the *gcd* $1$.

To get the maximum number of noncoprimes in $n+1$ numbers, we must choose maximum number of nonconsecutive integers from our set $\{1,2,3,\ldots ,2n\}$.

So if we can construct a set of $n+1$ numbers in such a way that we'll take maximum number of nonconsecutive integers, then if we get at least $1$ pair of consecutive integers in that set, then for the other $n+1$ numbers' sets, since there'll be less than or equal number of nonconsecutive integers than our maximum number of nonconsecutive integers' $(n+1)$-element sets, our proposition will automatically hold.

Since we've $2n$ consecutive integers in our set $\{1,2,3,…,2n\}$, we can take at most $n$ nonconsecutive integers. For the $(n+1)$-th number, since there's no nonconsecutive integers left, as we must choose another different integer from our set $\{1,2,3,…,2n\}$, it has to be a predecessor or successor of an integer we've already chosen. Therefore, we've coprime integers in our $n+1$ numbers. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 2):

Break up the set $\{1,2,3,\ldots ,2n\}$ into $n$ sets: $\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\ldots,\{2n-1,2n\}$. If we now pick $n+1$ numbers out of those $n$ ($2$-element) sets, as per [Pigeonhole principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) we will have two numbers picked from the same set. Those two numbers will be consecutive, therefore coprime.

Comment: Can we prove it using Pigeonhole Principal for the case where the numbers in all of our $n$ $(2$-element$)$ sets are not consecutive?

Comment: @Aleph-null There is no other "case" in this problem. It was down to *me* (in this solution) to partition the numbers, and I *deliberately* partitioned them as above. Maybe I don't understand what you are asking me?!

Comment: A different partitioning answers a different question. E.g. the partitioning $\{1,n+1\},\{2,n+2\},\ldots,\{n,2n\}$ can be used to prove that *there are two of those $n+1$ numbers which differ by exactly $n$*.

Comment: If there exists at least $1$ pair of coprime integers in our $n+1$ numbers, then we're done. To get the maximum number of noncoprimes in $n+1$ numbers, we must choose maximum number of nonconsecutive integers from our set $\{1,2,3,\ldots ,2n\}$.

Comment: So if we can construct a set of $n+1$ numbers in such a way that we'll take maximum number of nonconsecutive integers, then if we get at least $1$ pair of consecutive integers in that set, then for the other $n+1$ numbers' sets, since there'll be less than or equal number of nonconsecutive integers than our maximum number of nonconsecutive integers' $(n+1)$-element sets, our proposition will automatically hold. This is what @Stinking Bishop has done.

Comment: That is, Stinking Bishop first partitioned the set $\{1,2,3,…,2n\}$ into $n$ $(2$-element) sets of consecutive integers, then he just took $1$ number from each sets. But since we've $n$ $(2$-element) sets, we can take at most $n$ nonconsecutive integers. For the $(n+1)$-th number, we must choose another integer from one of the $n$ $(2$-element) sets, which is essentially a predecessor or successor of an integer we've already chosen.

Comment: In fact, we can do it without partitioning (but using the same concept). That is, since we've $2n$ consecutive integers in our set $\{1,2,3,…,2n\}$, we can take at most $n$ nonconsecutive integers. For the $(n+1)$-th number, since there's no nonconsecutive integers left, as we must choose another different integer from our set $\{1,2,3,…,2n\}$, it has to be a predecessor or successor of an integer we've already chosen.

Comment: @JalalAhmedChowdhury if you have an alternative proof, I suggest you add it as an *answer* (on top of your existing answer), rather than post it in comments here. Then it can be properly scrutinised, voted up (or down) etc. Otherwise, thanks for helping the OP understand my answer above.